# How To Protect File In Apps Build With Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3

I was build apps with codeigniter 3 for upload file.

file uploaded in https://site-com/uploads/file.pdf

How to protect my file already in apps, other visitor when not login cannot download this file.

thanks.

How To Protect File In Apps Build With Codeigniter 3